# Place 2 dropdowns in the same line

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this 2 dropdowns from bootstrap and i want to put them in the same row, i tryed to use the `<div class="row">` and the `<div style="display: inline-block;">` and it didn´t worked

```
<div class="row">
Ir Para: 
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="menu1" data-toggle="dropdown">Janeiro
    <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="menu1">
      <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Janeiro</a></li>
      //more dropdown content
    </ul>
  </div> de 
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="menu1" data-toggle="dropdown">2015
    <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="menu1">
      <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">2015</a></li>
      //more dropdown content
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: Have you tried: float:left for both dropdown divs

Comment: i placed it on the first dropdown and the two dropdowns stayed in the same line, but now i can´t click on the 1º dropdown, the 2º is working

Comment: did it work before the change?

Comment: yes, all was working right

Comment: I am not familiar with bootstrap, perhaps bootstrap has it's own float css class, use that one instead of manually setting float:left, something like:
bsFLeft:{float:left;}, then you add this class to the dropdown div.
I don't know the innerworkings of BS.

Comment: can you setup a demo on http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/3cr0opsm/2/ here you can see that the 1º don´t work and the 2º work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look this works for me, try it :
[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/g4Ltvsvy/)

```
      <div class="dropdown pull-left">
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="menu1" data-toggle="dropdown">Janeiro
    <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="menu1">
      <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Janeiro</a></li>
      <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Fevereiro</a></li>
        <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Outubro</a></li>
      <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Novembro</a></li>
      <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Dezembro</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div> 
</div>
  <div class="dropdown pull-left">
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="menu1" data-toggle="dropdown">2015
    <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="menu1">
      <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">2015</a></li>
      <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">2016</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: i can´t click on the 1º dropdown

Comment: My demo is working fine cross browser. Did you check it? And did you try to implement it this way in your app?

https://jsfiddle.net/g4Ltvsvy/

Comment: must have been one of my bug, now I can click, thanks

Answer (score 4):

There are two ways of doing this. First you can create a button group.
Since you are using two div elements, they both will need to have button group class. This method will have no space between the buttons on the same line
Here is the First Method ::

```
 <div class="btn-group">
Ir Para: 
  <div class="dropdown btn-group">
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="menu1" data-toggle="dropdown">Janeiro
    <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="menu1">
      <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Janeiro</a></li>
      //more dropdown content
    </ul>
  </div> de 
  <div class="dropdown btn-group">
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="menu1" data-toggle="dropdown">2015
    <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="menu1">
      <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">2015</a></li>
      //more dropdown content
    </ul>
  </div>
```

---

Second method ::

In the second method, you specify the grid span each button takes using col-*-* class. This method provides space between the buttons on the same line. Here is how it can be done::

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-md-2">
Ir Para: 
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="menu1" data-toggle="dropdown">Janeiro
    <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="menu1">
      <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Janeiro</a></li>
      //more dropdown content
    </ul>
  </div> de 
</div>
<div class="col-md-2">
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="menu1" data-toggle="dropdown">2015
    <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="menu1">
      <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">2015</a></li>
      //more dropdown content
    </ul>
  </div> 
</div>
```

---

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
.dropdown {
  display: inline-block;
}
```